# Does collation effect SQL Server replication

Tags: replication, sql-server-2016

I've been getting a replication error for some time now between my Publisher and Subscriber databases (SQL 2016). The error is the classic:

> "42000 The row was not found at the Subscriber when applying the
> replicated UPDATE command for Table '[dbo].[table_name]' with
> Primary Key(s): [field1] = ÊÀÏðÀËÎÀ, [field2] = 15501   ,
> [field3] = TS001    20598"

Table definition (both Pub and Sub):
field1 = PK CHAR(8) NOT NULL 
field2 = PK CHAR(8) NOT NULL 
field3 = PK CHAR(8) NOT NULL

If I query for that record in the Publication database using all the Primary Key values I get zero records returned. The same is true in the Subscriber database. The issue seems to be with the 'field1' value as the other two key values find matches in both publication and subscription dbs, but field1 is the unique identifier. Values in the Publication table for Field1 (when matching field2 and field3) are:
КАПрАЛОА
±КЛЇрОВА

I'm wondering if there is something going on here to do with collation or codesets as the Publication database uses a collation of Cyrillic_General_BIN (vendor specified!) but the hosting SQL instance  and the Subscriber database are both using Latin1_General_CI_AS. The publication properties are set to 'Copy collation = True' so it should be recognising the collation and passing it through.
The Publication server is also configured for a different language, hence the thought about the codeset.

If I create a new snapshot and publish that then all is well for a few days and then the issue happens again, but with different key values. I suspect that it's happening when the user changes the data. Other replicated tables do not seem to be affected in the same way as sometimes replication is successful (presumably when no changes tare made to table_name).

I've also tried adding verbose logging to the distribution job but the resulting file shows the same error as reported above and no more.

The fact that the field1 value does not exist in the Publication database is suspicious.

Any ideas where I can go next to resolve this issue?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: I've recently ran into the same exact error when replicating from a Publisher who's collation is different than my Subscriber's, and I actually specifically setup my Publication Articles not to copy the collation. But in my case this actually had nothing to do with the collation and rather had to do with my dedicated User for replication not having the appropriate Row-Level Security permissions to see the data on my Subscription database. Any chance you are using Row-Level Security or some other feature that could be potentially preventing your replication account from seeing the data?

Comment: I'm not using row-level security (vendor in the dark ages). The data is 'seen' by the distributer but it somehow gets a different value for field1 to what I see if I query the table directly.

Comment: Having seen the data in the subscription database it then tries to update the matching record in the publication database but, because the field1 has a different value to what is in both the subscription and publication dbs it is unable to complete the update and errors.

Comment: Sorry, i'm confusing the matter now as I transposed subscription and publication in my last comment. The data is seen in the publication db but is then somehow changed.

Comment: If I dig a bit deeper I can see that the Distribution.dbo.sp_browsereplcmds is returning '????????' for my field1 value (it's a char 8) rather than either of the values in my initial question. This is somewhat understandable since it's a CHAR field and unicode text. If the field were an NCHAR then maybe the sp_browsereplcmds would show the correct vales. This could be an indication of something going wrong since I can't verify the value of field1 in the Distribution database.

Comment: The ????... does sound related to your issue. I know Replication logs different parts of its process to some tables. Unfortunately I don't remember which off the top of my head but hopefully to give you something to keep you going, I would think those tables are in [this list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/replication-tables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) somewhere. If I get some free time tonight then I'll try do a little more digging.

Comment: I found that the data is copied to the Distribution.dbo.MSrepl_transactions and dbo.MSrepl_commands tables but it's in binary form and so isn't straight forward to read. I think that sp_browsereplcmds performs the 'decryption' of that data in returning it's results, but as explained above it doesn't do that cleanly. If that's the case then there does seem to be a collation or codepage when copying the data from the Publication db into Distribution but I don't know what I can do about it.